# When i read the xml file it reads duplicates of the node

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, xmlreader

When i try read my xml file it seems to reads it twice and im unsure on how to fix such an error. I thought i can have some sort of loop but im still lost. Any help would be appreciated ty. - It writes the xml file correctly but the duplicate occurs when it reads it.

```
String workingDir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
XmlTextReader textReader = new XmlTextReader(workingDir + @"\xmldoc.xml");

Console.WriteLine("BaseURI:" + textReader.BaseURI);
textReader.Read();

while (textReader.Read())
{
    if (textReader.Name == "test")
    {

        textReader.Read();
        XmlNodeType nType = textReader.NodeType;

        if (nType == XmlNodeType.Text)
        {
            //   label.Text = textReader.Value.ToString();
            Label l = new Label();
            System.Drawing.Point l1 = new System.Drawing.Point(15, 13 + a);
            l.Location = l1;
            l.Text = textReader.Value.ToString();

            a += 20;
        }
```

Comment: How you observed this - `it seems to reads it twice`?

Comment: If it's not sensitive data, can you also post a sample of the XML that is being read? It might help identify what's going on. Also, as an aside, if you're not expecting gigantic input, it might be more intuitive to use XmlDocument (or XDocument if you're feeling LINQ-y); I always find XmlReader leads to uglier code :)

Comment: FYI, you should not  be using `new XmlTextReader()`. That's been deprecated since .NET 2.0. Use `XmlReader.Create()` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What makes you think some entries are read twice? If it is the case, also check if this method is not called twice (shift + F12 in Visual Studio to find usage). 
Also, it seems that the piece of code you joined here is not complete (no declaration of variable 'a'). Do you have some code executed under the `if (textReader.Name == "test")` that would do the same operations?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what you are REALLY trying to do, and no visibility of you XML, but here is roughly how I would do it.

Notes:

1. I'm using an XmlReader <- Better IMHO (base class, so there's less waffle)
2. I'm using "reader.Value" without the ToString() as it's already a string type.
3. I changed it to be a switch as I think they are cleaner, but there are A LOT of XmlNodeTypes out there and you don't want to have to if/else to much!!!

Code:

```
        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("books.xml");
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            switch (reader.NodeType)
            {
                case XmlNodeType.Element: // The node is an element.
                    //DO NOTHING
                    break;
                case XmlNodeType.Text: //Display the text in each element.
                    //label.Text = reader.Value;
                    Label l = new Label();
                    System.Drawing.Point l1 = new System.Drawing.Point(15, 13 + a);
                    l.Location = l1;
                    l.Text = reader.Value;
                    a += 20;
                    break;
                case XmlNodeType.EndElement: //Display the end of the element.
                    //DO NOTHING
                    break;
            }
        }
```